# Phabricator pull/merge request

Tags: bitbucket, phabricator

Is it possible to do pull request in bitbucket style in Phabricator?

Eg. to branch off of some existing branch and then to create pull (merge) request to merge new branch back?

I see that Phabricator differential tool only allows to submit some manually entered diff to some branch. Is it the only way?

Answer (score 4):

You can mix `git` and `arc` together, but it does go against how `arc diff` is meant to be used.

You could leverage `audit` instead, although I haven't gone into any details about that below (nor have I used audit, yet).

Below, I've tried to explain our new workflow, coming from `git-flow` to an adapted version using `git` and `arc diff`.

### Background

Before we started using `Phabricator` we used `Gitlab` and created merge requests. These would get reviewed by another developer. We use `JIRA` and our workflow incorporates a `review required` stage which has several checks before progressing into testing.

At this point, we've pushed the branch to the remote, requested a review and awaiting testing to occur (we have a mix of both manual and automated testing).

Once the review has been accepted and tests have passed, the feature branch is merged into `origin/develop`.

### New workflow

Our new workflow removes the need to create the merge request within `Gitlab`, especially for reviewing.

My team still uses a workflow that incorporates `git-flow`, however, we've introduced the `arc diff` command. This creates the diff within Phabricator. The developer pushes his branch to the remote, but doesn't raise a merge request.

We run the following commands when creating a diff (merge into `origin/develop`)

```
git checkout -b feature/foo
git add <files>
git commit -m "A useful commit message"
git push origin feature/foo
arc diff origin/develop # this creates the diff within diffusion
```

Once the review has been accepted, we don't merge (or `arc land`) the branch, we await all testing to take place. This allows us to update the diff should testing fail and the developer who reviews can easily see which commits need reviewing.

Once testing has passed we can simply merge, either using `gitlab` merge request or the command line. We usually run `arc close-revision <revision-id>` to close the revision within Phabricator itself.

### Additional notes

I believe the philosophy of `arc diff` is that you don't push your local branch. Instead you create a `diff` which diffusion displays. This is classed as a `pre-push` workflow.

Phabricator also has a `post-push` workflow which incorporates audit. You can simply mark commits ready for audit by amending your commit messages.

Comment: GitLab CI can run tests, lints and review apps (deploy feature branches to dynamic environments) for merge requests, so there is no manual work for the same workflow. I can not see why Phabricator's arc diff workflow is better, I just see it provides the same, but with more manual work, because GitLab do it automatically.

Comment: Yup. that's right, and we use those features, but we were looking for a tool that gives us commit chunk history, so we could easily diff between commits, because sometimes additional commits are added after the initial review. I understand Gitlab allows you to diff between commits as well. Phabricator was just another tool we were evaluating.

Answer (score 3):

No, see https://secure.phabricator.com/T5000 to track this feature request.

Differential's primary input should be Arcanist, the Phabricator command line tool. It wraps git and provides lint, unit, and other precommit checks that help reduce time spent reviewing code. For example, it can emit patches and amend code before submission for review.

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist/